# "You are trying to save the file on a read-only disk" when trying to save a file in my home directory

Tags: permissions, read-only

I create a folder in my `Home` in Ubuntu and when I tried to save a text file I get

> Could not save the file “/home/martin/guradio/Text/qwe”.
>   You are trying to save the file on a read-only disk. Please check that you typed the location correctly and try again.

When I try to *right click > copy* move to desktop *right click > paste* the paste option is not active.

How can I make the folder writeable?

Tried running

```
sudo chmod 755 ~/guradio
```

But this did not fix the problem

Comment: Was it working before now, if so what did you do before this occurred!

Comment: Please show the commands used to create folder and used to attempt to create file, then run `ls -l ~/guradio` and the the result to your question

Comment: i create the folder in UI but i got it working after reboot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I restarted my laptop and when it booted I got a command interface instead of the GUI login screen.

I researched a little and ran `fsck /dev/sda2`. I had to fix the error by answering `yes`.

When I booted the system normally and tried saving it worked, so the problem is solved.

Comment: @sudodus i will update the answer if i remember the correct command interface. I see grub from there but it is different something like `imf`

Answer (score 1):

If Ubuntu is installed alongside Windows, uncheck *Turn on fast startup* in Windows with three steps:

1. Startup Windows
2. Access Control Panel > Power Option
3. Click "Choose what the power buttons do"
4. Click "Change settings that are currently unavailable"
5. Uncheck "Turn on fast startup"
6. Reboot and log in Ubuntu.

Comment: This is only true, if the filesystem is NTFS ... Since the OP fixed the problem by running `fsck /dev/sda2` and answering yes to fix errors, it was probably not NTFS.

Answer (score 0):

What happened to you is likely that you had a filesystem error (or a transient hardware glitch). In that case the HDD is remounted read-only to prevent further corruption (`errors=remount-ro` in /etc/fstab).

The error message you had ("*You are trying to save the file on a read-only disk*") was therefore correct. You could have checked that with `findmnt {mountpoint}` (likely `findmnt /`), and looking for `ro` (instead of `rw`) in the `OPTIONS` columns:

```
TARGET SOURCE          FSTYPE OPTIONS
/      /dev/something  ext4   ro,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered
```

The best course of action is to:

- immediately copy any important work to a **new** media (to avoid overwriting a valid (even if old) copy by something which is potentially corrupt).
- reboot and try to fix the problem (this may involve reinstalling to a new HDD it the worst case,  or just letting the system do an auto-repair if you are lucky).
- Install the `smartmontools` package, and check the [SMART data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) of your disk

  - Take the worst-looking numbers with a grain of salt, since some manufacturer encode several bytes of data in a single number (Google how to interpret these numbers for your disk model).
  - But don't overlook any disk health problems; You could have been lucky this time. Better change the disk while it's still usable (you can pick the right model/brand at the best prices since you have time), that having to to an emergency disk replacement at the work possible time (because this is when this happens: exams, project delivery, due to increased workload...)